# OpenLdap 2.4 on centos 6 doesn't listen on port 636

Tags: centos6, openldap, tls

I have an openldap 2.4 server on centos 6 whose confg I copied from those I have running under openldap 2.3 servers on centos 5 machines.

On openldap 2.3, specifying TLSCACertificateFile, TLSCertificateFile and TLSCertificateKeyFile with correct values makes the server listen on port 636. This is not the case on the openldap 2.4 setup.

I have configured it with loglevel -1 but I have not seen any clue as to what might be wrong and reading the openldap 2.4 manual doesn't indicate if any of the other TLS related parameters are now mandatory. I don't think so though because if I run the service manually, using "# /usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h "ldap:/// ldaps:/// ldapi:///"", the server does listen on port 636 and I can query it using "ldapsearch -H ldaps://myserver:636".

Is there something I am missing to get the server to listen on port 636 without having to always launch it manually? Is this linked to centos 6 or openldap 2.4?

Thank you.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On centOS 6/OpenLdap 2.4 you can turn on SSL/port 636 by setting SLAPD_LDAPS=yes.

- Edit /etc/sysconfig/ldap
- Set SLAPD_LDAPS=yes
- service slapd restart

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for, works great :-)

Answer (score 4):

For similar issues on CentOS 7.2 & OpenLDAP 2.4.40-9, you need to modify `/etc/sysconfig/slapd` and add `ldaps:///`. It would look like:

```
SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:/// ldap:/// ldaps:///"
```

Then restart `slapd` by:

```
service slapd restart
```

Thanks

Comment: That also works on CentOS 7.4. Before doing so, slapd doesn't listen on port 636, but afterwards, it looks like this: [root@openldap ~]# ss -turnlap | grep slapd | column -t
tcp  LISTEN  0  128  *:636   *:*   users:(("slapd",pid=18103,fd=10))
tcp  LISTEN  0  128  *:389   *:*   users:(("slapd",pid=18103,fd=8))
tcp  LISTEN  0  128  :::636  :::*  users:(("slapd",pid=18103,fd=11))
tcp  LISTEN  0  128  :::389  :::*  users:(("slapd",pid=18103,fd=9))